# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I've already tried doing some of the solutions found on the web none of them worked. I am using in-memory persistent hibernate database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private String id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String email;



    private Boolean enabled;


    private Event checkedInEvent;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="uuid", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "username")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void encryptPassword() throws Exception {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(password.getBytes());
        byte byteData[] = md.digest();
        //convert the byte to hex format method 1
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        password = sb.toString();
    }

    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    @Column(name = "enabled")
    public Boolean getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @PostLoad
    public void postLoad()
    {
        password = null;
    }


    @ManyToOne(optional=true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable
    (
        name="CheckedInUsers",
        joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="checkedInUsersId", referencedColumnName="id") },
        inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="checkedInEventsId", referencedColumnName="id") }
    )
    public Event getCheckedInEvent() {
        return checkedInEvent;
    }

    public void setCheckedInEvent(Event checkedInEvent) {
        this.checkedInEvent = checkedInEvent;
    }
}
```

## Checked in User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CheckedInUsers")
public class CheckedInUsers {

    private String id;

    private String checkedInEventsId;

    private String checkedInUsersId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "checkedInEventsId")
    public String getEvent() {
        return checkedInEventsId;
    }

    public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.checkedInEventsId = event;
    }

    @Column(name = "checkedInUsersId")
    public String getUser() {
        return checkedInUsersId;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.checkedInUsersId = user;
    }
}
```

## Event

```
@Entity
@Spatial(spatialMode = SpatialMode.GRID)
@Indexed
@Table(name = "Events")
public class Event {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private Date startTime;

    private Venue venue;

    private Set<User> checkedInUsers;


    @Id
    @DocumentId
    @GeneratedValue(generator="uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    @Field(name = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    @Field(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "starttime")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Field(name = "starttime")
    public Date getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(Date startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }


    @ManyToOne(optional=false,targetEntity = Venue.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="venueid",referencedColumnName="id")
    @JsonBackReference
    public Venue getVenue() {
        return venue;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "checkedInEvent")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    public Set<User> getCheckedInUsers() {
        return checkedInUsers;
    }

    public void setCheckedInUsers(Set<User> checkedInUsers) {
        this.checkedInUsers = checkedInUsers;
    }

    public void setVenue(Venue venue) {
        this.venue = venue;
    }

}
```

## error

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.save(Unknown Source)
    at Superior.TestCases.Config.TestDataSetup.setUpEastonEvents(TestDataSetup.java:130)
    at Superior.TestCases.Config.TestDataSetup.setUpVenues(TestDataSetup.java:81)
    at Superior.TestCases.Config.TestDataSetup.setUp(TestDataSetup.java:65)
    at Superior.TestCases.Tests.Models.TestAppManager.setup(TestAppManager.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3127)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3190)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
insert into CheckedInUsers (checkedInEventsId, checkedInUsersId) values (?, ?) [23502-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:307)
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:779)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:151)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:98)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

## The data that will be persisted

```
    user = new User();
    user.setUsername("billTheTester");
    user.setEmail("bill@google.com");
    user.setPassword("test123");
    user = daoManager.getUserRepo().save(user);
    this.testUserTwo = user;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Event event = new Event();
    event.setName("Hanging Out!");
    event.setVenue(venue);
    event.setStartTime(cal.getTime());
    event = daoManager.getEventRepo().save(event);
    testUserTwo.setCheckedInEvent(event);
    daoManager.getUserRepo().save(testUserTwo);
```

## Datasource Configuration

package Superior.Config.DatabaseConfig;

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Properties;


@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "Superior.Models",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "prodEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager"
)
@Order(1)
public class PrimaryDatasourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @Bean(name = "prodDataSource")
    public DataSource prodDataSource() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
//        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("hibernate.username"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "prodEntityManager")
    public SuperiorLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean prodEntityManager() {
        SuperiorLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new SuperiorLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(prodDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"Superior.Models.Tables"});

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        this.properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(em.getObject());
        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(prodEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        if(factory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
        }
        return factory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }

}
```

## hibernate.properties

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.query.factory_class=org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
hibernate.username=sa
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=loadtable.sql
```

## loadtable.sql

```
CREATE TABLE CheckedInUsers (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 checkedInEventsId varchar(35),
 checkedInUsersId varchar(35)
);
```

Comment: Add the code that going to persist some data.

Comment: Its been added. Thanks

Comment: Also, add the configuration of h2..

Comment: Ok, its done. Thanks

Comment: Nope :/ I've been trying to figure this out for a week lol. I put the project up on github. You can run the test cases.

Comment: Try to add `strategy = GenerationType.AUTO` in CheckedInUsers class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're using a separate JPA `Entity` to handle the relationship between the `User` and `Event`, which is seems unreasonable to me, since you can use `getCheckedInEvent()` and `getCheckedInUsers()` methods in order to get associated event with a `User` and get all users associated with an `Event`. So, if you delete the `CheckedInUsers` entity entirely, your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried this and keep in mind I am using In-Memory hibernate. I just removed the Entity and Table annotations from the CheckedInUser class. It still gives the same. error.

Comment: Are you sure it's in-memory not embedded file or something?

Comment: Well the reason I created the Separate entity was so it built the table for CheckedInUser. Now that I deleted the table I am getting the error `Unable to create unique key constraint (id) on table CheckedInUsers: database column 'id' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)`

Comment: Just for testing sake, rename the `JoinTable` on `getCheckedInEvent` to `CheckedInUsers2` and see what happens.

Comment: Now it said `Unable to create unique key constraint (id) on table CheckedInUsers2: database column 'id' not found` .

Comment: Add your spring configurations especially h2 related configs

Comment: Use this as jdbc url `jdbc:h2:mem:default`

Comment: And also, ignore the `import_files`. you don't need that too

Comment: So are you saying that hibernate generates a Join table by default ? Also I am getting the same error with `Unable to create unique key constraint (id) on table CheckedInUsers2: database column 'id' not found`

Comment: My test cases actually worked better when I had that CheckedInUsers Entity. It seem to only break when I saved users with those events.  Now all my test cases are breaking after removal of CheckedInUsers enetity

Comment: Yes it will generate the join table by default when you setting the `hbm2ddl.auto` to `create-drop` or `update`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105616/discussion-between-ali-dehghani-and-numerical25).

Comment: I take it you werent able to figure it out.

Comment: Your configurations are a bit unorthodox. I strongly recommend to use spring boot auto configurations. I'm afraid i can't help you anymore, i wish i could but ...

Comment: #Solution I was not able to find the exact solution because it started working all the sudden. But What helped was knowing that I did not need to create a 3rd entity for the join table. I just needed the two entities. So I will go ahead and give the answer to you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm analayzing the your prntstack:

```
...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
insert into CheckedInUsers (checkedInEventsId, checkedInUsersId) values (?, ?) [23502-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:307)
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:779)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:151)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:98)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.e
```

and in my opinion the real problem is in the id column af the your CheckedInUsers entity. in fact if you see the your code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CheckedInUsers")
public class CheckedInUsers {

    private String id;

    private String checkedInEventsId;

    private String checkedInUsersId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "checkedInEventsId")
    public String getEvent() {
        return checkedInEventsId;
    }

    public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.checkedInEventsId = event;
    }

    @Column(name = "checkedInUsersId")
    public String getUser() {
        return checkedInUsersId;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.checkedInUsersId = user;
    }
}
```

and the your sql for creatig the table:

```
CREATE TABLE CheckedInUsers (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 checkedInEventsId varchar(35),
 checkedInUsersId varchar(35)
);
```

I found that you declared the id property in java as a String and in sql as an int with the autoincremented strategy. I consider that the problem is here.

Now I don't know well the your domain but try to make the data type in your java code the same in the sql.

I Seeing the code and I see that you use SpringData, spring data creates a new object if the id is null and updates the object if the id is not null, however i know that for JPA exists a strategy that tract numeric id for entity and not string. I read from the code that you wish you had string has id, I can suggest to see the implementation that spring data for mongo use because for mongo the default strategy for id generation use uuid.

I hope that this can help you